# How can I add 1 to string value in each following request in Postman

Tags: variables, postman, postman-pre-request-script

I create users for the DB.
I need to send name and email. They should be unique, but not random. For example, the first user:

```
{
    "Name": "Panda",
    "Email": "pandaemail@test.com"
}
```

Then I need run collection with this request and automatically add 1 in the each following request for user creation.

User 2 should be:

```
{
    "Name": "Panda1",
    "Email": "panda1email@test.com"
}
```

User 3:

```
{
    "Name": "Panda2",
    "Email": "panda2email@test.com"
}
```

And so on.
How can I do this in Postman?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Set a variable in environment. For example, `counter=1`

Step 2: in Pre-request script:

```
let counter = pm.environment.get('counter');

if (typeof(counter) === 'string'){
    counter = Number.parseInt(counter);
}

let name = "Panda" + counter;
pm.environment.set('name', name);

let email = "Panda" + counter + "email@test.com";
pm.environment.set('email', email);

pm.environment.set('counter', counter + 1);
```

Step 3: in Body:

```
{
    "Name": "{{name}}",
    "Email": "{{email}}"
}
```